# Why JSON.parse is not working?

Tags: javascript, json

I set the dataType to 'text' because I don't want to Jquery parse my JSON automatically.
My code is the following:

```
var membId = '5';
$('#submitNewDescription').live('click',function(){
    //An ajax request is made to update the DB
    $.ajax({
        url: '../../cgi-bin/qualification.py',
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({newDescription:$('#newDescription').val(),id:membId}),
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: 'false',
        success: function(data){
            json = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);
            console.log(json);
        }
    });
});
```

And it returns that string: {"error":["ORA-01031 insufficient privileges"]} in both console.log commands. It means that the parse isn't working since it doesn't return a JavaScript object. JSONLint says to me that is a valid JSON.

Anyone has an idea of what is happening?

### Thanks

EDIT

I can set to 'json', it is not problem. The problem is that JSON.parse and $.parseJSON should work. Since they are not, I changed 'dataType' to 'json', but the same string is returned. I have no idea what is happening.

Comment: Why don't you want jQuery to parse the JSON automatically?

Comment: If the parsing is not successful, `json` would not contain the string, but would be `undefined`. There must be something else. Sure that `json` is not an object? What does `typeof json` give you? Also note that `json` is a global variable (which it should not be).

Comment: What browser you'r using? I tried it with ff3.6 an it worked perfect. try [link]http://jsfiddle.net/scheffield/URDBv/

Comment: It is funny how simple things are some time. The problem was that. json was not a global variable, I just forgot to declare it. And instead JS tell me that is undefined, it though was better to not parse.@Felix Kling

Answer (score 7):

Probably because you're looking for [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) instead? Also I *beieve* jQuery will look at the data and make a best-guess at parsing it before passing it off to the callback. So, if it looks like JSON chances are jQuery's already giving you a JavaScript object back which then *can't* be re-parsed using `JSON.parse`/`$.parseJSON`.

You can also change your `dataType` field to 'json' and let jQuery do it for you...

Comment: Definitely just let jQuery do it for you.

Comment: @MattBall: Agreed. And my "can" was more an implied "should". But since s/he is deciding against it (for whatever reason), I just thought I'd throw it out there. Though it doesn't make sense to put it off until the success function only to then (first line) convert it.

Answer (score 2):

change **`dataType: 'text'`** to `dataType: "json"` and also `JSON.parse` to `$.parseJSON`

Answer (score 1):

The `JSON` library doesn't exist in all browsers. You might need to include your own like http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/json/

Or like the others suggested, use the jQuery one. You might also want to declare `json` like `var json = ...`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got it to work as follows:

- from the server (a servlet), I specified json as the data type of the response
- the jquery call then already parses the response param into a JSON object (so I didn't need to run $.parseJSON) ... thank you https://stackoverflow.com/a/6465506/2162226 !

Notice I can: ***access the json field directly in the response object***

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        data: theData,
        success: function(response) {

                alert(' status = ' + response.status);
                processResponseJSON(response);
        },
```