# why parseJSON returns null

Tags: jquery, json

I have following jQuery/JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.getJSON("http://example/topics", {}, function(data){
           console.log( data ); // display the JSON *data* in the web console
           console.log( $.parseJSON(data) );
  });
</script>
```

**console.log(data)** shows JSON data within firebug console (firefox add-on), but **console.log( $.parseJSON(data) )** shows **null**.

what could be possible reason.

I need to convert JSON string into array.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume because [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) already parsed the data. `data` is  Javascript object.

> The `success` callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed using the `$.parseJSON()` method.

Of course we could say more if you show us the output, but normally, `$.getJSON` already parses the response.

P.S.: I hope you use a proper URL in your real code.

Answer (score 2):

Try validating your json string, i'm guessing it's not valid (and could not be parsed because of this): http://jsonlint.com/