# Parsing JSON string returns null

Tags: jquery, json

I'm quite new to JSON handling and I've got myself stuck. My page contains the following script;

```
<script type="text/javascript">



$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#progressBar').progressbar({value: 0.0});


    process();
});
    function process() {

        getStatus();
        setInterval(getStatus,1000);
    }

    function getStatus() {
        $.getJSON('status-report', function(data) {
            var statusBean = $.parseJSON(data);
              $('#progressBar').progressbar('option','value',$.trim(statusBean.percentComplete));
            $('#status').html(statusBean.statusDescription);
        });
    }


</script>
```

Using Firebug, I can see that the call to 'status-report' is returning a JSON string

```
{"statusBean":{"percentComplete":50.0,"statusDescription":"Default Description"}}
```

but after `$.parseJSON`, Firebug shows me that the variable `statusBean` is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `data` is already a JavaScript object. `getJSON` parses the response for you. It is described in the documentation: *"The `success` callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed using the `$.parseJSON()` method."*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why parseJSON returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465468/why-parsejson-returns-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `data` as passed to the `getJSON` callback, will already be a JS object. `$.parseJSON` will return `null` when an object is passed to it, as it expects a string. The call to `$.parseJSON` can simply be removed here, since `getJSON` assumes JSON in the first place.